# Google Chart is not showing inside Polymer 2.0 element

Tags: javascript, polymer-2.x, google-visualization

I am trying to add Google chart in my polymer element but it's not showing inside it though it is working fine when I am adding this in my index.html. I was using **google-chart** from **GoogleWebComponent** but it was not working anywhere,so I moved to their gstaic library. I have searched many times for the solution and some SO answers are saying that adding callback will fix the issue but I am unable to do so.below are my codes for the element which is responsible for rendering the chart and the screenshot. In screenshot the first one is the one residing in index.html which is working fine below one is the one inside polymer elements which is not working.

```
<!--
@license
Copyright (c) 2015 The Polymer Project Authors. All rights reserved.
This code may only be used under the BSD style license found at http://polymer.github.io/LICENSE.txt
The complete set of authors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/AUTHORS.txt
The complete set of contributors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/CONTRIBUTORS.txt
Code distributed by Google as part of the polymer project is also
subject to an additional IP rights grant found at http://polymer.github.io/PATENTS.txt
-->

<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<dom-module id="routing-chart">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;

      }

      #org-chart{

          width: "100%";
          height: "100%";
      }


      .chartNode{
        background: red;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
      }

      h3 {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-left: 34%;
        color: cadetblue;
      }

      .refresh {
        padding-left: 38%;
      }
      .refresh-background {
        background-color: var(--primary-color);
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
        #org-chart {
          width: 300px;
        }
      }
      #container {
        margin-left: -2%;
        margin-top: 10%;
        margin-bottom: 10%;
        margin-right: 10%;
      }
      @media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 375px) {
        #org-chart {
          width: 370px;
        }
      }

      @media (max-width: 320px) {
        /*#routing_chart{
          width: 300px;
        }*/
      }
      @media (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 375px) {
        /*#routing_chart{
          width: 320px;
        }*/
      }
      @media (min-width: 376px) and (max-width: 425px) {
        /*#routing_chart{
          width: 380px;
        }*/
      }
      @media (min-width: 426px) and (max-width: 768px) {
        /*#routing_chart{
          width: 500px;
        }*/
      }
      @media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
        /*#routing_chart{
          width: 850px;
        }*/
      }
      @media (min-width: 1025px) {
        /*#routing_chart{
          width: 1000px;
        }*/
      }
      google-chart{
        width: "100%";
        height: "100%";
      }
    </style>

    <!-- <paper-material id="root" elevation=3> -->
      <div id="container">
      <!-- <div><h3>Routing Info</h3><span class="refresh"><paper-button class="refresh-background" raised
                                                                    on-click="loadDataForChart">
        <iron-icon icon="icons:refresh" style="color: #FFFFFF;"></iron-icon>
        </paper-button>

      </span></div> -->
<!--
      <div id="org-chart">
        <google-chart
          id="routing_chart"
          style="height: 100%;width: 100%"
          type='org'
          loading="{{isloading}}"
          options='{"title": "Routing Table"}'>
        </google-chart>
      </div> -->
      <div id='org-chart'></div>
      </div>
    <!-- </paper-material> -->

  </template>
  <script>
      google.charts.load('current', {packages:["orgchart"]});
      // var org-chart=document.querySelector('#container');
      // orgchart.addEventListener('dom-change',function (){
      //   console.log('dom-change');
      // });
      class RoutingChart extends Polymer.Element{
          static get is() { return "routing-chart"; }

          static get properties(){
              return{
                  hubId: {
                      type: String,
                      value: '01-00-00-14-00-01-00-00',
//            observer: 'loadDataForChart',
                      notify: true
                  },
                  isloading:{
                      type:Boolean,
                      notify:true
                  },
                  setGraph:{
                      type:Boolean,
                      value:false,
                      notify:true,
                      observer:'loadDataForChart'
                  }
              };
          }
          constructor() {
              super();

          }
//          hubChanged(){
//              this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#routing_chart').data=
//          }
          loadDataForChart() {
              if(this.setGraph==undefined) return;
              var t = Date.now();
              if(this.setGraph){

                  this.drawChart();

              }
          }



          drawChart() {


              var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
              data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
              data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
              data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

              // For each orgchart box, provide the name, manager, and tooltip to show.
              data.addRows([
                [{v:'0', f:'0<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">HUB</div>'},
                 '', 'The Hub'],
                [{v:'1', f:'1'},
                 '0', 'Node 1'],
                ['2', '0', 'Node 2'],
                ['3', '1', 'Node 3'],
                ['4', '3', 'Node 4']
              ]);

              // // Create the chart.
              // var divElement=document.createElement('div');
              //
              // document.getElementById('org-chart').appendChild(divElement);
              var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#container'));
              // Draw the chart, setting the allowHtml option to true for the tooltips.
              chart.draw(data, {allowHtml:true,chartArea: {
                  width: '100%'
              },width:'100%'});

              var chart2 = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('org-chart'));
              chart2.draw(data, {allowHtml:true});

        }

      }

      customElements.define(RoutingChart.is, RoutingChart);

  </script>
</dom-module>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your Div Container is inside the template. So instead of

`this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#container')`

use

`this.$.container`

and it should work as aspected.